# Why is overflow interacting with z-index?

Tags: css, overflow, z-index

I am trying to understand the rules behind z-index and how it interacts with the overflow property.

I have this html:

```
<body>
  <div class="cell">
    Here is some text to keep things interesting
    <div class="boxy"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And this css:

```
.boxy {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top:70px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0FF;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid #F00;
  position: relative;

  /* comment these two lines out and the box appears */
  /* or change them both to 'visible' */
  /* changing only one of them to 'visible' does not work */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I would have expected that the cyan box appears even though it is out of the size of the `div.cell` because its z-index and its position are set.

However, the only way to make the cyan box appear is to comment out the overflow-x and -y lines.

My question is: How can I make the cyan box appear on the screen while keeping the overflow as either hidden or auto?  But more importantly, I'm looking to understand *why* this is happening. What are the css and layout rules being applied here?

[See my Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/lR8jpeyiYmkRusyRLkVp?p=preview) This example, is of course a much simplified version of the HTML/CSS I am actually working with.

---

**EDIT** 
There seems to be some confusion in the answers below because I didn't explain things well enough. If you comment the two overflow lines out, you can see that the cyan box appears. It appears outside of the border of `.cell`.  Why does this happen? How can I make the cyan box appear, while still hiding overflow and z-index?

Comment: remove the position

Comment: Which position? And why would that work? What are the rules going on here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason the cyan box appears only when `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are visible, and disappears otherwise, is simply because the cyan box is overflowing the cell box. `overflow: visible` simply means "paint this box even if it is overflowing its containing block" — the cell box is the containing block of the cyan box because its `position` is relative. Any other values of `overflow` cause overflowing content to be clipped from view. There is nothing special going on here; in particular, the z-index is completely irrelevant and there is no such interaction as the question title alludes to (and there really is no reason to set it to such a huge number unless you're worried about scripts injecting other elements into the cell).

The only way to allow the cyan box to appear while the cell has a non-visible overflow is to remove `position: relative` from the cell and apply that declaration to the parent of the cell (in your example, it's the body). Like this:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.boxy {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 70px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0FF;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid #F00;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  Here is some text to keep things interesting
  <div class="boxy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. I think I get it now. `overflow` controls what happens to DOM stuff outside of the visible boundaries of the element. `z-index` has to do with stacking of visible elements. So, if an element is not visible, it cannot be stacked. Thanks for the clarification. ps- in the actual application, I use saner values for z-index. 9999 was only to prove (to myself) that the problem was not about a z-index that was too low.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg: The element can still stack - you just don't see it when overflow is not visible. It's why layout isn't affected by scrolling.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means that my approach will not work since it relies on `.boxy` having a position relative to `.cell`. By placing the `position: relative` higher up the DOM, I need to use JS to calculate proper positioning of each `.boxy` element.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Hi Andrew, I've encountered the same issue you had. Just wondering how you solved it.

Comment: In the end, I had to rearchitect this part of the dom. I had been trying to implement popups with locally defined dom elements. The change was to create a single popup dom element dangling off of the root that displays, hides, and moves based mouse interactions with the local dom elements. I'm not 100% pleased with the solution because scrolls are janky, but it is better than before.

Answer (score 4):

Absolute-positioned elements do not contribute to the dimensions of their parents.

Therefore, the `.cell` DIV has no content that affects its dimensions, making it 100% wide by 0px high.

To make the element appear, you'll have to add a height to `.cell` that will encompass the DIV, in this case 120px (70px top + 50px height).

Comment: I understand the part about the .cell having no dimensions. I made a slight change to the question so that the parent div has text in it.  But I do not want to make the `.cell` have a height. I am adding the element to the z-index since I want it to float above the other elements. My goal here is to create a sticky tooltip that moves along with the element it points to.

Comment: Ahh, I understand your question better now.  Interesting.

Comment: Interesting, indeed. :) I just hope there's a silly little thing I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

The Parent Class **cell** need to be set it's height.  because height of `absolute` element doesn't  affect it;s parent.

```
 .boxy {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9999;
      top:70px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #0FF;

    }

    .cell {
      border: 2px solid #F00;
      position: relative;

      /* comment these two lines out and the box appears */
      /* or change them both to 'visible' */
      /* changing only one of them to 'visible' does not work */
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: auto;
      min-height: 120px; /* height 70px(Top)+50px*/
    }
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I don't want `.cell` to change its height based on `.boxy`.  You can see that if you remove the two `overflow` lines, the box appears, and it is outside the location of `.cell`.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem**

Your problem is related to `cell` node that hides `boxy` when `overflow` is specified on `cell` node.

**The reason**

The reason behind is that `boxy` with position absolute does not contribute to `height` of `cell` and `overflow` hides it.

**Why is it shown without overflow?**

By default `overflow` is `visible`, which for browser means *do not do anything special for overflow functionality* and it does not need to render overflow => does not hide `boxy`.

Comment: Adding the height and width make the `.cell` larger, but that's not what I want. I want `.boxy` to float above all other elements, outside of the `.cell`.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg then just use `relative` instead of `absolute`, look updated version.

Comment: Not really. That only works when you move the box into the coordinates of the cell itself. I want the box to be visible even when it is outside the boundaries of `.cell`. This happens when you comment out overflow.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg for that case you have to write some javascript, because `.boxy` cannot be outside without absolute positioning and cannot contribute to height with it. Relatively good option would be to have absolutely position `.boxy` and set `height` of `.cell` with javascript when it is inside of it.

Comment: Why does this work when there is no overflow set? I don't need to set the height of `.cell` in that case.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I guess it is, because by default `overflow` is `visible`, and for browser that means **do not do anything special for `overflow`**, but when you specify `overflow: auto` it detects `cell`'s `height` and renders overflow in a way that hides `boxy`.

Answer (score 1):

Z-indices are *local* inside their clipping hierarchical parent context.  This is very non-intuitive.  They have their own z-stack context, which normally parallels that of the enclosure hierarchy.  But they're still subject to clipping!  Which can be a real pain if you're intuitively expecting the z-indices to be *absolute*.

Note that some jquery containers, such as accordion, quietly specify overflow: auto.  Even if it's not explicitly in *your* code.  (This can be overridden locally after it's found.)

Also note that if overflow-x: visible is set, but overflow-y is set to a non-visible, then the rendering engine quietly internally changes overflow-x to be the same as overflow-y for your amusement.  But you found this out already.

You probably should be able to circumvent the unwanted non-"visible" overflow clipping, even with your high z-index, by invoking `transform: translate(0,0);` [or whatever desired offset, % or pixels] inside the style of the div that you want to levitate.  Transform should create a new local z-stack for that element and its children.  Which will let you get around an overly-restrictive parent or grandparent.